# postscript variable syntax (.ps file)

Tags: file, postscript

I have a large .ps file. There are some variables defined but I am not able to figure the length of the variable.

I am picking some part of the code, it is like a four column and multiple row matrix.

```
 .../$v.HDLE_UNIT_TOTAL ex 31.752 103.752 220.4 2 10.0 0.0 0 vsE  //31.752 must b x axis?
 /$v.PKGE_QTY_TOTAL ex 69.48 213.48 220.4 2 10.0 0.0 0 vsE....   //213.48 must b y asix?
   // what defines the length of that variable?
```

Comment: FYI, `//` does not introduce a comment in postscript. `%` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely impossible to say what this PostScript snippet does without access to the complete PostScript program/file.

At the very least one needs to know what `vsE` means. This must be defined elsewhere in the file (more to the front in a statement similar to

```
/vsE {some-PS-code} def
```

Comment: Hi - I have another question, I checked the postscript completely. But could not find definition for 'ex' and 'VarEx' defined after some of the variables.

Comment: Would you know the difference like if they are defined as 0.1 0.2 /var_a ex 0.2 0.3 /var_b VarEx

Comment: @oneofthelions: no, there is not any chance for me to guess what that could mean. Would you know the meaning and value of any of 4 cryptically-named variables in JavaScript, if you saw just two lines cut from within a `.js` file using them?

Comment: @oneofthelions: BTW, just curious -- why did you tag this question with `[pdf]`? Does PDF come into play somewhere with your problem?